# How to make sure Altium routes GND mostly on the bottom layer where there's a polygon pour?

Tags: ground, altium, gnd-pour

I've tried routing before and after pouring a GND on the bottom layer. I get many GND traces running on the top layer for no apparent reason? Tried without a GND layer, added it after the auto-router - but it did not help.

Any idea what would be the best way to make sure the router puts a via near SMD components that should connect to GND on the bottom side and not run traces?

Answer (score 3):

> *Tried without a GND layer, added it after the auto-router - but it did
> not help.*

It's simple; don't use an auto-router. The details in your question clearly indicate that your auto-router is stupid so, don't use it. If you insist on using your auto-router then manually connect GND tracks to the ground-plane with vias and delete the offending track.

In all my history of designing PCBs, I've never used an auto-router and I don't intend to start any time soon.

Comment: You'd think that auto-routing would be a solved problem by now - at least for not too complex boards, but despite advances in AI and processing power of seems like we're still not there...

Comment: Apparently, for those designing backplanes, it's useful @brhans. Probably because connector positions are a fixed thing mechanically.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer.